# C# MVC Getting folder location in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that i am extending and bought some code for ease of implementation. I have a string of code that i have used in the past.

```
Server.MapPath()
```

In this code they are using something else

```
MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot()
```

In this isn't it just as easy to replace the code above with a (~)? Or is there something else going on in this that i do not see.

I cannot seem to find a NuGet package for this MicrosoftHelper either. I have searched the web for it and also Nuget but in this code it exists as a .dll

The entire line of code looks like this:

```
sb.Append("<li class=\"\"> <a href=\"" + MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot() + "/" + item.Menu_MenuId.MenuURL + "\"><i class=\"fa fa-angle-double-right\"></i>  " + item.Menu_MenuId.MenuText + "</a></li>");
```

Comment: I also could not find anything about a library or reference to `MicrosoftHelper`. Perhaps they are using an alias? eg `using MicrosoftHelper = Reference_to_dll??`

Comment: @Mark This is from Meta data.. Assembly MicrosoftHelper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. There is also a an insert in the Views Webconfig under <pages pageBaseType ="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"> <add namespace="MicrosoftHelper" />. I added it to my project from the other project, However in there packages folder there is a folder called MicrosoftHelper that has the dll in it. I added it and do not have that folder. I am not sure what it is so i am not sure that i should use it..